# Xcode: How do i change the merge tool in Xcode 7.x?

Tags: xcode, merge, xcode7

Xcode 7 and Git. Earlier answers to this (earlier versions of Xcode) no longer seem to be valid. I want to use P4Merge because FileMerge is *terrible*, it doesn't consider the closing brace of a function to be part of the function, so it interleaves functions as they are compared

Comment: Why dont u use source tree,as it propmts to open the external merge tool when u have merge conflicts and u can choose P4Merge from the options ?

Comment: Trying to keep my pipeline simple, used to be able to change the merge tool in Xcode and would prefer to keep my current workflow, but that's my backup.

Comment: did u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719122/how-to-use-opendiff-as-default-mergetool ?