# How can I successfully change my default mergetool utility to opendiff

Tags: xcode, git, mergetool, opendiff

I *initially* did the commands mentioned in [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

I did:

```
git config merge.tool vimdiff
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
git config mergetool.prompt false
```

*Then* I did the commands mentioned [How to use opendiff as default mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719122/how-to-use-opendiff-as-default-mergetool)

I did both:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
git config --global merge.tool opendiff
```

I also checked it with:

```
$ git config --global merge.tool
```

and terminal says it's `opendiff`

However when I do git `mergetool` it reverts back to using `vimdiff`.

If I try the 2nd solution in the linked answer ie do:

```
$ git mergetool -t opendiff
```

Then it works for once.

So how I can permanently change it to `opendiff`

Comment: verify .gitconfig  file in userprofile directory

Comment: what about it should I verify?

Comment: [diff]
    tool = opendiff

Comment: it's set to `opendiff`

Comment: Can you see my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ```
> > git config merge.tool vimdiff
> > ```

This configures Git to use vimdiff *for this repository only*.

> > ```
> > git config --global merge.tool opendiff
> > ```

This configures Git to use opendiff for *all repositories that don't have a more-specific configuration*, i.e., all repositories *except* the one you configured earlier.

> > ```
> > git config --global merge.tool
> > ```

This asks Git: *What tool would you use if I weren't in **this** repository, or **any other repository that has an override set**?*

To make Git use the default, *remove the local override:*

```
git config --unset merge.tool
```

(note: no `--global`).

Comment: Hah! I just did `git config merge.tool` (without the `--global`) and it returned `vimdiff`.This just helped me better understand the `--global` option. Thanks

Comment: Right, that would ask Git: *what tool should you use for **this** repository?*  Which of course was your override setting.